# Custom UITableViewCell: SIGABRT on "loadNibNamed:"

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to get the hang of doing a subclass of UITableViewCell with a custom nib file.

The subclass's name is MyCustomCell. The .xib file just has a UITableViewCell with a single UILabel "cellTitle" and I've connected it to an outlet in the UITableViewCell subclass.

In the class in MyCustomCell that returns the cell, I get a SIGABRT error on the following line:

```
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:NULL];
```

Here's the implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";

myCustomCell *cell = (myCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = (myCustomCell *)[myCustomCell cellFromNibNamed:@"myCustomCell"];
}
//TODO: Configure Cell
return cell;
}
```

Here's the implementation for myCustomCell cellFromNibNamed:

```
+ (myCustomCell *)cellFromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName 
{
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:NULL];
NSEnumerator *nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
myCustomCell *customCell = nil;
NSObject* nibItem = nil;
while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) 
    {
    if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[myCustomCell class]]) 
        {
        customCell = (myCustomCell *)nibItem;
        break; // we have a winner
        }
    }
return customCell;
}
```

I get the SIGABRT error in the line

```
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:NULL];
```

in the above method. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the comment about your nib name from @Seega which seems reasonable you have numerous issues in the nib loading code;

```
+ (myCustomCell *)cellFromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName 
{
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:NULL];
NSEnumerator *nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
myCustomCell *customCell = nil;
NSObject* nibItem = nil;
while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) 
    {
    if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[myCustomCell class]]) 
        {
        customCell = (myCustomCell *)nibItem;
        break; // we have a winner
        }
    }
return customCell;
}
```

Your `customCell` instances is nil so sending it the `class` method is a no-op and returns nil. In that case `isKindOfClass:` is not going to return what you think.

Also, don't iterate through the list of objects returned from the `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method. Instead create a connection between the file's owner and the cell in the nib file so that it gets set when the nib loads. Then change your code to look like this;

```
+ (myCustomCell *)cellFromNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName {
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];
  myCustomCell *gak = self.theFreshlyLoadedCustomCellThingSetUpInIB;
  // clean up
  self.theFreshlyLoadedCustomCellThingSetUpInIB = nil;
  return gak;
}
```

Also, it is atypical to name a class with a lowercase character. Others reading your code will think that is a variable and not a class. Call it `MyCustomCell` instead.

Comment: Can you address what you mean by self.theFreshlyLoadedCustomCellThingSetUpInIB? In examples I've seen, people either iterate through the contents of the nib, or simply use objectAtIndex:0 because they assume that's where it should be as nothing else should be in there.

Comment: Sure, set up an outlet in the class of self above (a view controller?) that points to the table view cell. When you load the cell the NSBundle code will set that outlet to the cell.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use the string parameter "nibName" instead of @"View"

```
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of problems in my code as people have pointed out. The issue that was causing the actual problem I was talking about in the title turned out to be an issue in IB: I had outlets referencing file's owner rather than the actual objects.

But I'm giving this one to Bill because he addressed the largest number of mistakes...