# UILabels Blocking Cell Selection on Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 4 custom UITableViewCell subclasses generated from nibs that all include UILabels. I noticed that I am not able to select the cell when I tap on the frame of the UIlabel. Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Can you select the cell when you click on the empty area of the cell where none of the UILabel frame intersects? 

  Also wondering.. did you implement -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;    Also if you select the tableView on your .xib file... is the "Selection" = "Single Selection"?? [http://i.stack.imgur.com/AOZah.png]

Comment: Yes I am able to select the cell when clicking outside the frame of a UIlabel. Yes, I did implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Also yes to your last question.

Comment: BTW I am logging the didSelectRow method and I can confirm that it is being calledwhen I click around the UILabels.

Comment: Try running it on your simulator... then go to "Debug" menu at the top menu bar and select "Color Blended Layers"... it will show you where the frame actually are... OR you could set different background color for UILabel and see if the frame is set properly as how you wanted it.

Comment: I did the color blended layers and realized I was wrong about the tapping working outside the frames. The row selections don't necessarily happen outside the UILabel frame. The selections seem to work towards the bottom of each cell and work better on larger height cells. Any thoughts on what the issue could be? I don't think the issue is related to userinteraction enabled.

Comment: Did you fixed it.i too have this issue. but my custom cell is not loaded from nib.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that you can set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` so touches aren't intercepted by the UILabels.

Answer (score 2):

Go into UIBuilder and select the labels, and make sure that userInteractionEnabled (it's under the view properties) is set to no.

Comment: The userInteractionEnabled is already set to No. Any other ideas?

Comment: @NewCoder Well, I'd test turning it on then in case my memory is completely backwords.  But in all honestly, that makes me suspect that something else is going on.

Comment: I tried turning it on and I think you are right about it needing to be off. I bet something else is going on and I'm looking to see if there is any other relevant info I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. I needed to set the entire UITableViewCell subclass nib to userinteractionenabled = NO. In my init method of each subclass I added the following code:

```
       [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ROIUITableViewCellType1"
                                  owner:self
                                options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.mainView];
```

The subview from the nib obscured the cell which was responding to tap events. I am not sure if this is the proper way to load a nib for a UITableViewCell subclass which may have caused my problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yea, I was thinking there was another view that is intercepting the touches... but When I make custom cells, I usually do it this way... [Look at the first answer with 3 upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898060/custom-uitableviewcell-sigabrt-on-loadnibnamed)